# jQuery, if H1 contains certain text, do something

Tags: jquery, contain

For some reason this simple code isn't working.
I'm loading info from an API to a H1 element. Then, based on that info, I want to add some text to another H1 element right next to it. I've given both H1 elements ID's and tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#constructor').is(":contains('McLaren')")) {
    $('#foundYear').append('1963');
  }
});
```

Nothing happens.

Edit: I'm using Angular to get data from the API. Here's the HTML:

```
<header>
  <img src="img/flags/{{talli.nationality}}.png" />
  <h1 id="constructor">{{talli.name}}</h1>
  <h1 id="foundYear"></h1>
</header>
```

Edit2: To really understand what I'm trying to do, I added a picture, and here's some more details: 
I'm using NG-repeat to load Formula 1 constructors from the Ergast API. Then, add a little bit of my own info as well, such as foundation years for each constructor. I don't really know how to approach this, since I'm still quite new to Javascript.

[image]

Comment: This code is valid, I don't know what's the problem .upload code.

Comment: please share your mark up code also.. are you laoding H1 using ajax call?

Comment: @Pilot  His code is perfectly valid. he must have other problem

Comment: @RoyiNamir sorry about that

Comment: @Pilot I would go this way too, because it makes it more readable. But the OP code works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/bb284quy/

Comment: We need to see the markup.

Comment: I'm using angular to get dynamic content. Here's the html:

Comment: Put the HTML markup in the question.

Comment: @Klisee IMHO - you're using angularJS. so I assume that your document ready happens BEFORE NG doing its digest.  just to check if i'm right try this :`$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        if ($('#constructor').is(":contains('McLaren')"))
        {
            $('#foundYear').append('1963');
        }
    }, 2000);
});`

Comment: When you check the source code of the generated page, is the text there?

Comment: Still not working. And the text does now show up in the source code. I'll get back to this later.

Comment: So that's the problem. Once your text is there, your code will work just fine.

Comment: I added some additional info and a pic.